# Filter all cells which are not empty

Tags: excel

I have close to 40 columns in my excel sheet..Now, I need to filter all the rows where 40 columns are populated.

**cell1 cell2 cell3 cell4**

```
1     1        1   1
      2        2   2
               3   3
```

Now, I need the 1st row only in my output.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Is the data you showed the source data, or the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Say your data is in the forty columns from column **A** to column **AN**.

In cell **AO2** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A2:AN2)=40,"X","")
```

and copy down.  Then AutoFilter column **AO** to display only the ***X*** rows:

[image]